# What is the difference between Standard error and Relative std. error?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, standard-error

I have a report with both Standard error and  Relative std. error for a same metric for two years.

What is the difference between Standard error and  Relative std. error in this example?

How should I explain these two terms for general audience?

```
Date        Metric A (%)    Standard error (%)  Relative std. error (%)
16.02.21    475,98             12,7              2,8
16.02.20    690,83             12,4              1,9
```

Comment: I assume RSE = SE/Metric.

Answer (score 0):

It simply is standard error of the estimate divided by estimate itself multiplied by 100. For example (12.7/475.98)*100. It is to create a perspective for the scale of error. You wanna know what is the proportion of your error to your estimate.